# Can't connect to postgresql in R if dbname contains € character

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I need to access different databases which contain symbols $ and € (or other currencies)

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
get_connection <- function(connection = current_connection)
{
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = connection,
                   host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                   user = "postgres", password = "dbpass")
  con
}
c <- get_connection("€18")
```

and catch error

```
 Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@localhost on dbname "€18"
)
```

names with $ work like a charm, but then i use euro symbol I get error.

Is it problem of PostgreSQL driver? Is there any way to walkaround this? Maybe another type of connection to postresql?

Comment: Could you please try writing db name with double quoted in string like c <- get_connection('"€18"') or c <- get_connection("\"€18\"")

Comment: Yes, I've tried it before asking. It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I used official postgresql ODBC driver. and it works ok with any schema name. If somebody needs solution let me know